# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL Xubuntu 12.10 AMD open source

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu

I am trying to compile the example from the following website: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/

At first `CMake` was unable to find libGL.so, so I pointed it to where the lib is (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so) in the txt file. After that I tried `make all` and this gave me the following `error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`. According to what I found this means that ld is unable to find libGL.so, but if I type `locate libGL` I get the following response:

```
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Cave Story+/lib/libGLU.so.1
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.6
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.6.0
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.08004
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/doc/nvidia-cg-toolkit/examples/Tools/trace/libGL.so.1.gz
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.6
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.6.0
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.08004
/home/jacko/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime.old/i386/usr/share/doc/nvidia-cg-toolkit/examples/Tools/trace/libGL.so.1.gz
/opt/cave-story-plus/lib64/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libGLSL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libGLSL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libGLSL.so.1.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/libGLSL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtcreator/plugins/Nokia/libGLSLEditor.so
/usr/lib32/libGL.so
```

Which looks to me like libGL is fully available.

also:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgl1-mesa-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I am running Xubuntu 12.10 with opensource AMD drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else encounters this too: the symlinks between /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so was gone. I did `sudo apt-get remove --purge libgl1-mesa-dev` and `sudo apt-get install ibgl1-mesa-dev* libglu1-mesa-dev* libqt4-opengl-dev* qt-sdk*` to fix this.

Comment: You shouldn't have to purge first. Simply installing the mesa dev packages brings it into existence.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this simple script will help someone. The 1 answer helps me too but this script finish what was missing.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEPENDS='libx11-dev'
DEPENDS+=' libxmu-dev'
DEPENDS+=' libglu1-mesa-dev'
DEPENDS+=' libgl2ps-dev'
DEPENDS+=' libxi-dev'
DEPENDS+=' libglfw-dev'
DEPENDS+=' g++'
DEPENDS+=' libzip-dev'
DEPENDS+=' libglew*-dev'

MISSING=
echo "Checking for missing packages ..."
for i in $DEPENDS; do
    if ! dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' $i | grep "install ok installed" > /dev/null; then
        MISSING+="$i "
    fi
done

if [ -n "$MISSING" ]; then
    TXTCOLOR_DEFAULT="\033[0;m"
    TXTCOLOR_GREEN="\033[0;32m"
    echo -e $TXTCOLOR_GREEN"Missing packages: $MISSING.\nYou may be asked for your password for package installation."$TXTCOLOR_DEFAULT
    sudo apt-get --force-yes --yes install $MISSING
fi
```